# React-Select input contents disappear when select is not focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I've been using react-select happily for a while, but am having a problem regarding the `Creatable` version of the component.

Here's my code:

```
const options = [
  {
    label: 'One',
    value: 'One'
  },
  {
    label: 'Two',
    value: 'Two'
  },
  {
    label: 'Three',
    value: 'Three'
  },
  {
    label: 'Four',
    value: 'Four'
  }
];

const selectedItems = [
  {
    label: 'One',
    value: 'One'
  }
];

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Select.Creatable
      backspaceRemoves={true}
      multi
      openOnFocus={false}
      openOnClick={false}
      onSelectResetsInput={false}
      onBlurResetsInput={false}
      onCloseResetsInput={false}
      arrowRenderer={() => null}
      clearRenderer={() => null}
      options={options}
      value={selectedItems} />
  </div>
);
```

I've also created a runnable version of this here: https://codesandbox.io/s/q27lnon96

As you can see if you access the Sandbox page, any text entered into the select disappears when the user clicks away. It re-appears if the select is given focus again.

[image: Here's a GIF recording of the behaviour]

To be explicit, my question is about the text "two" that is entered into the input - it's not an issue with the selected values (These work fine if the correct state and callbacks are configured).

How can I make react-select preserve the contents of the input? It seems like it is remembering the value internally, but hiding the text input when it no longer has focus. I thought that setting the various `onFooResetsInput` all to false would accomplish this, but it hasn't quite worked.

My application is using the value of the text entered into this input to affect other elements of the UI, so it appears out of sync when the text is hidden.

- react-select version: 1.2.1 (Latest)
- react and react-dom versions: 15
  or 16 (both exhibit this behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to handle onChange event and also make selectedItems part of your component state. In you case selectedItems never change.

take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/pyo17y6qv7

**Edit**

Yep it works with inputRenderer. The default argument of the function pass the value to the input (this is the reason why input value disappear because when it is onBlur it pass value '' to the input. Likely a bug on react-select because we have onBlurResetsInput flag false) so we need to remove it before we pass it to our own input. Updated code on https://codesandbox.io/s/54on0mr984

Comment: Thanks, but this still exhibits the problem. My issue is not with the selection items, but the contents of the textbox (The string being used to filter the options in the dropdown - in my example the text "two"). Sorry if that wasn't clear from my GIF. I've edited the question to hopefully make it a bit more clear.

Comment: yep just realized that I read your question lol. I think there maybe a bug related to react-select library if onBlurResetsInput = false doesnt work. You may need to add this property to pass your input component like inputRenderer={() => <input />}. but if you do it his way you need to have a state to keep track of what is current value of the input and also spend some effort to style it.

Comment: @MattHolland yes i think inputRenderer approach works

Comment: I just had to explicitly hide the placeholder text when there was a value in the input (Otherwise it appeared superimposed): `placeholder={!filterValue ? placeholder : null}`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested in solution for **react-select version2**.

Below solution works for **react-select v2**.

> Docs - https://react-select.com/upgrade-guide#concepts

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { default as ReactSelect } from "react-select";



function Select(props) {

    const [inputValue, setinputValue] = useState('')

    const onInputChange = (inputValue, event) => {
        if (event.action==='input-change'){
            setinputValue(inputValue)
        }  
    }
    
    return (
            <ReactSelect
                onInputChange={onInputChange}
                inputValue={inputValue}
            />
    )
}

export default Select
```